# SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag ajax, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my controller,

```
public ActionResult ReturnMethodTest(int id) 
{
    string name = "John";
    return Json( new {data=name});       
}
```

I am trying to get data from this controller by using code below but I am getting [image: Syntax error] .

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
        url: @Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "HomeController"),
        data: {
            id: 5,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: try this:`url: '@Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "HomeController")'`

Comment: My Code looks like this  $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "Home")',
        data: {
            id: 5,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); And firebug throws "500 internal Server Error" /http://i59.tinypic.com/5y96ok.png

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`@Url.Action` only returns the action url's string, without quotes around it.

You'll need to wrap that url in quotes.

Replace:

```
url: @Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "HomeController"),
```

With:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "HomeController")',
//   ^                                                 ^
```

Otherwise, the file returned to the client will contain:

```
url: /HomeController/ReturnMethodTest,
```

Which isn't valid JS, nor what you want. The replacement gives the following result:

```
url: '/HomeController/ReturnMethodTest',
```

Which is a perfectly valid JavaScript string.

Comment: My Code looks like this $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "Home")', data: { id: 5, }, success: function (data) { console.log(data); } }); And firebug throws "500 internal Server Error" /i59.tinypic.com/5y96ok.png

Comment: In that case, my answer worked, but there's _also_ a problem in your controller / action, server-side. I'd suggest posting a new question for that, including controller code, if you can't fix that error.

Comment: Ok I fixed this, I need to add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet to my controller like this <code> return Json( new {data=name}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); <code>

Answer (score 2):

A Javascript *regular expression literal* looks like this -- a pattern enclosed between slashes:

```
var re = /pattern/flags;
```

If you interpolate a variable that begins with a slash but do not put quotation marks around it, it will be interpreted as a regular expression, not a string. Another time this comes up is with JSP expression language, where you should write the first, not the second:

```
var spinner = "<img src='${contextPath}/images/ajax-loader-small.gif'>"
var spinner = "<img src='" + ${contextPath} + "/images/ajax-loader-small.gif'>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `Controller` suffix while specifying in `url`.

Try it this way:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ReturnMethodTest", "Home")'
```